# User upload of multiple image files to channel entry via channel form

Tags: devdemon, channel-images

I'm trying to set up a front-end file upload form, in which the user uploads (max 2) image files to a channel entry.

I've seen reference to DevDemon's Channel Images as being the likely candidate to enable this functionality, but I can't find any reference material on the DevDemon site or anywhere that indicates how to accomplish this within EE Channel Form.

Does anyone have something they can point me at? Or know where I can find a tutorial / reference file or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I can't get this to work either.

Comment: No, never got it resolved. We had to change the upload process to single file only. If anyone does find out what the issue is, I'd be interested to know too.

Answer (score 0):

Channel Images does exactly this. You can set a max amount of images to be uploaded. And also resize the images on the fly.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the front-end syntax to do that? The '{exp:...' method statement, parameters, etc? Unless I've missed something, I can't see where to find the information to do that, either on the DevDemon site or elsewhere.

Comment: You restrict the parameters in the field settings itself. Go into your field settings and click the different tabs.

Comment: OK, I'm using a plain template page, with just channel form, the channel images field and jQuery as an include parameter in the channel form tag. I can upload files into the Channel Images field, but when clicking on submit, the field clears and no images are saved into the entry. How do I debug this??